# How do I add functionality to the exit button without System.exit(0)?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I went through and had the program System.exit(0) whenever the user clicked the window's red exit button. Is there a more efficient way to add functionality to that button?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

class codeWithProblem
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String name, gender, passions, enjoy;
        int yesNo, permission, endProgram;
        String prefix = "";
        while (true)
        {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
            if (name.equals("null"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "So your name is           "+name+". Is this correct?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (yesNo == -1)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (yesNo == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a boy or a girl?: ");
            if (gender.equals("null"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if ("boy".equalsIgnoreCase(gender)||"girl".equalsIgnoreCase(gender))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ("boy".equalsIgnoreCase(gender))
        {
            prefix = "Mr. ";
        }
        if ("girl".equalsIgnoreCase(gender))
        {
            prefix = "Ms. ";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's nice to meet you "+prefix+name+".", "Hello", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        permission = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Lets ask some easy questions to start out with. Is this okay with you?: ",
        "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (permission == 1)
        {
            endProgram = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to end this program? Click CANCEL to end and OKAY to continue.",
            "End Program?", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (endProgram == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good, lets continue...", "Continue", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                permission = 0;
            }
            if (endProgram == 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye....", "END", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        if (permission == 0)
        {
            passions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What are some of your passions?: ");
            if (passions.equals("null"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            enjoy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Why do you enjoy "+passions+"?: ");
            if (enjoy.equals("null"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That's interesting", "hmmm", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program has no point and is going to end now.", "BACON", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? And why do you want to avoid `System.exit`?

Comment: I want to be able to add functionality to the Red Exit button without having to use that if statement everytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which window's red button are you talking about?

This one?

[image]

If so, then you can implement a `WindowListener` for your `JFrame`:

```
JFrame f = ...;
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
      System.exit(0);
   }
});
```

Or you can simply set the default close operation:

```
JFrame f = ...;
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I'm not making a JFrame. It is just pop up prompts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting the program to exit when the user presses the X button, you can do something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Greeter");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//Add your questions to the frame
frame.setVisible(true);
```

That way, when the window gets closed, the program exits.

Oracle has excellent (and really simple) tutorials on Swing (the Java windowy stuff) for beginners [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/index.html). They are part of the overall [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work even with what you have done.

When the user presses the [image] button, the value of the from input box will be null.

```
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
```

If the user closes the dialog (no matter whether a value is entered or not) you get a `null`. `null` not `"null"`. (the latter is a string).

So when the user closes the dialog `name.equals("null")` will throw the null pointer exception.

And for handling this close button is easy, check whether the value is null when you know that.

```
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
if (name != null)  //Proceed only when the user has entered a valid name
{
    yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "So your name is "+name+". Is this correct?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (yesNo == -1)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (yesNo == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

**The basic problem** is that you have a infinite loop. You need to break out of the loop,you can use `break` but then you have another infinite loop. Add a null check on this name to the other loop also:

```
while (name != null)  //Enter this loop only when the user has entered a name
{
    gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a boy or a girl?: ");
```

BTW, I assume that this is some sort of learning what you are doing here. This is definitely not good in *real* apps. And, you can merge the two loops, you need only one, not two.